# How to handle failure scenarios for Glue Streaming?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-glue, amazon-kinesis, data-stream

I'm working on Glue Streams, can someone help me understand on how to handle the data when Kinesis or Glue Job fails.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/crafting-serverless-streaming-etl-jobs-with-aws-glue/

https://catalog.us-east-1.prod.workshops.aws/workshops/976050cc-0606-4b23-b49f-ca7b8ac4b153/en-US/300/330-streaming-lab